# Does numpy.where always output the indices in an ascending order?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D boolean array `a`, for example

```
a = numpy.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype='bool')
```

I want to use `numpy.where` to find the indices of the True elements

```
idx = numpy.where(a)[0]
```

Can I assume that the output `idx` is always sorted in an ascending order? Does `numpy.where` guarantee that? I am asking this question because the document does not say anything about it and the `numpy.where` is written in C, which is not obvious to tell how it works.

Comment: Calling `numpy.where` without a condition is equivalent to `np.asarray(arr).nonzero()` (which should be used instead of `numpy.where` in this case).  `nonzero` guarantees that: "The values in a are always tested and returned in row-major, C-style order."  If you're interested in the source, it's [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/18a6e3e505ee416ddfc617f3e9afdff5a031c2c2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2318).  You can clearly see the array is iterated in Row-major order.

Comment: Additionally, there's an article about `row-major` order in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)

Comment: ＠user3483203 So does it mean that it will always return an array of indices in ascending order?

Comment: For a 1D array, yes, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If absolute maximum speed is not of utmost importance you can simply code out your assumption explicitly:

```
idx = np.arange(len(a))[a]
```

That said, `np.nonzero(a)` is guaranteed to give the indices in order as per the documentation. It's just slightly less explicit than the above, but will be faster.